# How can the charge on a plate of a parallel plate capacitor (even if grounded) ever be zero, given that the other plate will create a field

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I recently came across this answer [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193258/grounding-a-capacitor#:~:text=As%20a%20rule%20of%20thumb,though%20it's%20voltage%20is%20zero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193258/grounding-a-capacitor#:%7E:text=As%20a%20rule%20of%20thumb,though%20it%27s%20voltage%20is%20zero).
while studying capacitance. Based on this, I have a few questions

1. Firstly, as the other plate is still charged, won't it induce a voltage on the other plate? The other post just mentions the voltage on the plate is zero, while having an equal and opposite charge
2. Secondly, if the earth is creating an opposing charge, how is that calculated?
   As this is my first question on physics stack exchange, if you downvote, please let me know why, so that I can ask better quality questions in the future.

Comment: Welcome to SE. The title of the your question doesn't describe what your problem is and will be useless in a search engine. Please make sure that the title communicates the general topic of your question.

Comment: I've edited the title, is it better now?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> won't it induce a voltage on the other plate?

The constitutive relationship for the capacitor with capacitance $C$ is
$$V = \frac{Q}{C}$$

Where $V$ is the potential difference between the plates and $Q$ is the charge on each plate (positive on one plate and negative on the other).

So whatever the charge is on one plate, exactly the opposite charge is found on the other plate, and the voltage difference between the plates is determined entirely by this charge.

What you might be confusing is that knowing the potential difference between the two plates doesn't mean you know the potential difference between either plate and the reference ground for your circuit.

One of the plates might be connected to the reference ground, or they might be connected through other circuit elements so that neither is specifically grounded. You need to analyze the complete circuit, rather than just the capacitor in isolation, to know the potentials relative to the reference ground.

> Secondly, if the earth is creating an opposing charge, ...

The earth is usually considered as an infinite charge sink. It can provide or absorb as much charge as is necessary to keep whatever is connected to it at the same "earth" potential.

But that doesn't mean that connecting (one node of) your circuit to earth will change the potential difference between any two nodes in your circuit.

> ...how is that calculated?

By doing the analysis of your circuit, and finding the potential difference across the capacitor. Then from $V=\frac{Q}{C}$, you can determine the charge on the capacitor plates.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for the prompt reply, I have a few doubts, however, what I'm still not able to understand is why the other plate's potential is zero, given that it's in an electric field

Comment: @fhhh, it's zero because the choice of what node in your circuit you call the reference ground is arbitrary, and you chose this node to be the point of zero potential.

Comment: so we're neglecting the voltage created by the external field by introducing a correction factor of sorts, right?

Comment: @fhhh What external field?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the field due to the other plate

Comment: I'm very sorry if this doubt is stupid

Comment: The potential difference between the two plates is determined by the integral of the electric field along a path between the two plates. But that doesn't tell you the potential (relative to reference ground). It only tells you the potential difference between the two plates. (Remember that when you calculate the integral of the electric field there is an arbitrary constant of integration --- which is determined by your choice of reference potential)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the clarification! Everything makes sense now.