# How to calculate capacitance of system in which the two plates are not equally oppositely charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

How to calculate the capacitance of a system of parallel plates (not connected to anything else) in which the two plates have charges $Q$ and $-2Q$ (say); that is, they are not equally oppositely charged?

Comment: For capacitors with linear dielectrics, the capacitance doesn't depend on the charge on the plates. It is determined by the geometry of the plates, and the dielectric constant of the material between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the "charge on a capacitor" defined when two plates are unequally charged?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519925/) and the links therein. Also enter [capacitor unequal charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=capacitor+unequal+charge) into the sires search engine for many more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitance of a system depends only on the geometry of the system and not on the charges added to it.

However I suspect you might be more interested in how the charge distributes itself in the sort of system you describe, and the answer is that for a system of parallel plates the charge distribution obeys three rules:

1. the charges on the surfaces facing each other are equal and opposite
2. the charges on the two outermost plates are identical
3. if any plate in the system is earthed the charges on the outermost surfaces are zero

Given these rules, the charge distribution in your system would look like this:

[image: Charges]

When calculating the potential difference between the plates we can ignore the outer charge and consider only the $\tfrac32Q$ charge on the inner surfaces. The reason for this is that we can approximate the plates as infinite since the separation is typically much smaller than the size of the plates, and the field from an infinite plate is constant and does not decrease with distance from the plates.

This means everywhere in between the outer surfaces the fields from the $-\tfrac12Q$ outer charges cancel to zero:

[image: Field due to outer charges]

The net field is due only to the $\tfrac32Q$ charge on the inner plates. Therefore the potential difference between the plates is the same as if just has a symmetric $\pm\tfrac32Q$ charge on the plates.

Comment: From a problem , I came to know that if capacitance is C then potential difference will be 3Q/2C . So I got confused as to why V is not equal to q/C where q = | -2Q+Q|=Q . In the case of a concentric spherical capacitor we take the total charge but in this case why are we only taking in inner side charges while calculating potential difference?

Comment: @GarvChaudha I've edited my answer to address your comment.