# Electric field becomes non-conservative in electrostatic problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance

This question is about what I think was a misinterpretation of the statement of an exercise. But first I have to give some context. The question is at the end.

During a class, my professor wrote the solution for the following problem:

> Find the capacitance of two parallel cables of radii $a$, very large length $L$ and separated by a distance of $2d$. Both cables are also at a distance $h$ from an infinite grounded plane. Assume $2d >> a$, and the charge density is the same for both cables.

To find the capacitance (thing which I don't particularly care now) one needs first the potential difference. Before he started to write equations he said that:

> Since the cables have the same charge, and they are symmetrical vertically and horizontally respect to the plane, then both are at the same potential.

Then he started to solve the problem with the image method. Remove the grounded plane and put another pair of cables with opposite charge, such that the distance between the true cables and the fictitious ones become $2h$.

[image]

The potential that comes from just one cable is:

$$V_i = -\int_0^r \vec{E} d\vec{r} = \frac{Q}{2\pi L\epsilon_0} \ln \left( \frac{r_i}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|} \right) $$

Where we assumed that $V(0) = 0$, since this was imposed when we had the grounded plane. Now, the total potential is: $\sum_{i=1}^4 V_i$. What changes is the value of $\vec{r_i}$ and since the pair of ficticious cables have opposite charge, will be -Q the charge for them. I don't want to put all the computes here. But the supposed result is that the potential difference between the real cables is:

$$\Delta V = \frac{Q}{2 \pi L \epsilon_0} \left[ \ln \left(\frac{2 \ln2d}{a \sqrt{4d^2+4h^2}} \right) - \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{4d^2+4h^2} a}{2d+2h} \right) \right] $$

Here comes the problem. Undo the image method step. Remove the fictitious cables from below and put again the grounded plane. Now I think on what my professor said at the beginning. That is the statement that confused me. Because if both cables are at the same potential, the potential difference between them should be zero. But the result that I showed doesn't seem to convey the feeling that the field is conservative at all, because the path won't be independent. Can I have a non conservative field in an electrostatic situation? Am I missing something?

What I think is that the lines (cables) *have to* be opposite charged in order to make sense and then the assumption of same potential becomes false—my professor misunderstood the excersice. So, if this is the case, two more questions arise:

- does this mean that if both cables had same charge (with same sign) then $\Delta V$ would be equal to zero and the capacitance is not defined, hence the problem doesn't make sense at all?
- if the cables were opposite charged, still could I use the image method like in the solution, but with the fictitious cables being opposite charged?

P. S. Note that I'm not asking for any computation in particular. I present here the equations that I could copy just to give some context.

Comment: I think you are right, the cables should have opposite charges (and hence different potentials) to have a meaningful capacitance. That is because of the common definition of capacitance https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225407/. If we think to the case of the classical square-plated capacitor (with Q and -Q charges), then by increasing the potential difference one can increase the accumulated charge on each of the plates, as Q = C V, by induction. This is not possible in the example in which cables have the same charge.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have both real cables at the same potential, and calculate capacitance. Since both real cables are assumed at the same potential, $\Delta V$ for them is zero, and $\Delta V$ you gave is between some other pair of bodies which are at different potentials, maybe between the real and the imaginary cable, or ground.

Comment: In case the two cables are at the same potential, capacitance of the system is defined simply as $Q/V_c$, where $V_c$ is electric potential of the cables. Since potential of the ground is zero, $V_c$ is also potential difference between the cables and the ground (the other "plate" of the "capacitor").

Comment: Electric field is conservative in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To find the capacitance (thing which I don't particularly care now) one needs first the potential difference. Before he started to write equations he said that:
>
> > Since the cables have the same charge,...

The key question here is, to find the capacitance of *what*?

In a system of three conductors we can find the mutual capacitance between any two of those conductors, or we can find the self-capacitance of any one of the conductors.

Your instructor is following a procedure that will find the mutual capacitance between the two wires (taken as a single electrode) and ground. In signal integrity engineering this is an important property of the wires because it determines how common mode signals (usually undesirable, but often present and responsible for producing undesired radiation) will behave on these wires.

If you want to you can also find the mutual capacitance between the two wires. That's also an important property of the wires, but it's not the one your instructor is solving for here.

> But the result that I showed doesn't seem to convey the feeling that the field is conservative at all,

If I understood correctly, you have calculated the potential of the first wire (call it A) considering only its own charge and its image charge. Then you calculate the potential of the second wire (call it B) considering both its own charge and image charge and the charge of wire A. This is why you calculate a different potential for A and B.

But the charge on B has just as much effect on the potential of A as the the charge of A has on the potential of B, and you neglected that contribution.

From the symmetry of the geometry, it's certain that with equal charge on the wires there will be no potential difference between A and B. If you found a difference then you must have made an error somewhere, even if I haven't understood correctly where the error lies.

> Can I have a non conservative field in an electrostatic situation?

No, if you solve Poisson's equation correctly for the electrostatic potential you will obtain a conservative field.

> What I think is that the lines (cables) have to be opposite charged in order to make sense and then the assumption of same potential becomes false

Two conductive bodies near each other have mutual capacitance between them. That capacitance exists whether they are (differently) charged or not. We must (in our minds, at least) charge them to calculate or measure the capacitance. But the capacitance doesn't become undefined or uncertain when we (by whatever means) keep the two bodies at the same potential.

> What I think is that the lines (cables) have to be opposite charged in order to make sense and then the assumption of same potential becomes false—my professor misunderstood the excersice.

We can force the wires to be at equal potential simply by connecting them together at some point (far away from the point where we're evaluating the fields, to be sure that the connection doesn't disturb the fields there). So having the wires at equal potential is not a non-physical scenario. As mentioned before, it's actually one that's very important for signal integrity engineers.

In your statement of the problem, it isn't made clear which mutual capacitance is meant to be calculated, so if you have transcribed the problem statement completely it does seem that the problem is ambiguous.

---

Edit to add:

> The potential that comes from just one cable is:

$$V_i = -\int_0^r \vec{E} d\vec{r} = \frac{Q}{2\pi L\epsilon_0} \ln \left( \frac{r_i}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|} \right) $$

This looks like a solution for the potential on an isolated wire in space referenced to a 0 potential at infinity. You could use this to find the self-capacitance of the wire.

But the isolated wire in space will have its charge distributed evenly around its circumference.

The wires in your scenario with 2 wires and a ground plane will not have even charge distribution on their surfaces. Therefore you can't simply superimpose the solution for 4 isolated wires to find the potentials in your problem, unless we're taking the statement $d\gg a$ to mean the wires can be treated as thin wires (simple lines of charge).