# Basics of Capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance

Looking at the formula $C = \frac{Q}{U}$ does a high capacitance mean that with a low voltage we can bring more charge onto the capacitor? How is total charge on the capacitor linked with voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the potential difference across the plates of the capacitor $U$ is kept constant then the charge stored on the capacitor $Q$ is proprtional to the capacitance $C$, ie $Q\propto C$.

On the other hand if the capacitance $C$  is constant then the charge stored on the capacitor $Q$ is proportional to the potential difference across the plates $U$, ie $Q\propto U$.

Comment: Can theoretically a capacitor have different charges stored on the two opposing poles?

Comment: It could. [What would be the capacitance of an unequal charged capacitor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225407/what-would-be-the-capacitance-of-an-unequal-charged-capacitor/632106#632106)